# Test a Reactive-Kafka Consumer and Producer Template using embedded kafka + custom serialised

Tags: spring-kafka, reactive-kafka

We need an example on how to test `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate` and `ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate` with an `embedded-kafka-broker`. Thanks.

**CORRECT CODE IS HERE AFTR DISCUSSION**

You can have your custom `de-serializer` accordingly to use custom `ReactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate`

**Custom Serialiser:**

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class EmployeeSerializer implements Serializer<Employee> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Employee data) {
        
        byte[] rb = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            rb = mapper.writeValueAsString(data).getBytes();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rb;
    }

}
```

**Use it part of embedded-kfka-reactive test:**

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.reactive.ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.condition.EmbeddedKafkaCondition;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.KafkaTestUtils;

import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderOptions;
import reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

@EmbeddedKafka(topics = EmbeddedKafkareactiveTest.REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC,
brokerProperties = { "transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1", "transaction.state.log.min.isr=1" })
public class EmbeddedKafkareactiveTest {

    public static final String REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC = "reactive_int_key_topic";

    private static final Integer DEFAULT_KEY = 1;

    private static final String DEFAULT_VERIFY_TIMEOUT = null;

    private ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<Integer, Employee> reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate = new ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplate<>(setupSenderOptionsWithDefaultTopic(),
                new MessagingMessageConverter());
    }

    private SenderOptions<Integer, Employee> setupSenderOptionsWithDefaultTopic() {
        Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils
                .producerProps(EmbeddedKafkaCondition.getBroker().getBrokersAsString());
        SenderOptions<Integer, Employee> senderOptions = SenderOptions.create(senderProps);
        senderOptions = senderOptions.producerProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "reactive.transaction")
                .producerProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true)
                .producerProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName())
                ;
        return senderOptions;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_When_Publish() {
        
        
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        
        ProducerRecord<Integer, Employee> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<Integer, Employee>(REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC, DEFAULT_KEY, employee);
                
        StepVerifier.create(reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.send(producerRecord)
                .then())
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }   

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        reactiveKafkaProducerTemplate.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tests in the framework use an embedded kafka broker.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/main/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/reactive

```java
@EmbeddedKafka(topics = ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplateIntegrationTests.REACTIVE_INT_KEY_TOPIC, partitions = 2)
public class ReactiveKafkaProducerTemplateIntegrationTests {
...
```

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's better to edit the question and comment that you have done so. I need to see the complete test and the actual exception.

Comment: Thanks. I have added.

Comment: Please see my edits for proper markdown to format code. `setupSenderOptionsWithDefaultTopic()` - if you copied that from the framework tests then, yes, it sets up an `IntegerSerializer` for the key and `SrtringSerializer` for the value - you need a value serializer that can handle your `Employee` object, such as the `JsonSerializer`.

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not convey any useful information. If you mean you are still getting the same error, it means you are not setting the property properly. If it is set properly, it will work. I can't tell from the code snippet what you are doing. Add the complete test, not just snippets.

Comment: It's not the same problem, it's a different error. There are two issues. 1. You are using the wrong `JsonSerializer`; it should be `import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;`. 2. You are creating a transactional producer and using a non-transactional send. Your test passes with a non-transactional producer and the correct serializer.

Answer (score 0):

added correct serialised with a non-transactional producer. please see the code on top of this page for the answer.